# Passing a list into a array which holds a JSX.Element which get passed to other components

Tags: reactjs

i have a difficult problem with my coding logic. My goal is to define a component list with propertys that holds the informations and get passed into a other components. Its used to generate the sidebar Elements depending only on this array und display the selected Component in ToolFrame. The code below works, but when i want to pass the "list" array from internal area to ToolList, i should pass this via props to ToolList in order to pass it into the Batchlookup like this:

`<BatchLookup list={props.list}/>`

But it has to be a function in order to do this and then i got problems to pass things around, i tried some suggestions, but im kinda stuck here. Is this even the right way to do this or should i rethink the logic? Is there a possible solution to get the JSX.Element out of props.selectedTool in ToolFrame und append the list as prop there? Do you guys have a clue?

Thank you for helping.

Here the code:

ToolList.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import {
  AutoStories as AutoStoriesIcon,
  ManageSearch as ManageSearchIcon,
  BugReport as BugReportIcon,
  BugReport,
} from "@mui/icons-material";
import BatchLookup from "./BatchLookup";
import GlossaryIndex from "./Index";
import ReportBug from "./ReportBug";

const ToolList =  [
    {
      key: "Batch-lookup",
      label: " identifier lookup",
      accentColor: "#2078B5",
      icon: <ManageSearchIcon />,
      tool: <BatchLookup />,
    },

    {
      key: "index",
      label: "index",
      accentColor: "#F07E21",
      icon: <AutoStoriesIcon />,
      tool: <Index />,
    },
    {
      key: "bug-report",
      label: "Report a bug",
      accentColor: "#D72829",
      icon: <BugReportIcon />,
      tool: <ReportBug />,
    },
  ];


export default ToolList;
```

InternalArea.tsx:

```
import React, { useSe } from "react";
import { OidcSecure } from "@axa-fr/react-oidc";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import ToolFrame from "../components/tools/ToolFrame";
import SideBar from "../components/sidebar/SideBar";
import ToolList from "../components/tools/ToolList";



const InternalArea = () => {
  const [tool, setTool] = useSe<JSX.Element>(ToolList[0].tool);
  const [open, setOpen] = useSe<boolean>(true);

  const List = [    {
    term: "identifier ",
    type: "type",
    color: "#2078b5",
    definition: "Identifier Type text without something",
    predicates: [
      {
        term: "predicate  1",
        type: "predicate",
        color: "#209cb5",
        definition: "Predicate Type text without something",
        daype: "string",
      },
      {
        term: "predicate  2",
        type: "predicate",
        color: "#20b52c",
        definition: "Predicate Type text with something",
        daype: "number",
      },
      {
        term: "predicate  3",
        type: "predicate",
        color: "#b52020",
        definition: "Predicate Type text with something 2",
        daype: "object",
      }]
  },
  {
    term: "identifier ",
    type: "type",
    color: "#59b520",
    definition: "Identifier Type text with something",
    predicates: [
      {
        term: "predicate  1",
        type: "predicate",
        color: "#b58120",
        definition: "Predicate Type text without something",
        daype: "string",
      },
      {
        term: "predicate  2",
        type: "predicate",
        color: "#20b52c",
        definition: "Predicate Type text with something",
        daype: "number",
      },
      {
        term: "predicate  3",
        type: "predicate",
        color: "#b520b5",
        definition: "Predicate Type text with something 2",
        daype: "object",
      }]
  }];

  const exampleFilteredPredicateListbyChoosenIdentifier = [ ...glossaryList[0].predicates ];

  const takeToolSwap = (selectedTool: any) => {
    setTool(selectedTool);
  };

  const takeOpenSe = (sideBarOpen: boolean) => {
    setOpen(sideBarOpen);
  };

  return (
    <OidcSecure>
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <SideBar takeToolSwap={takeToolSwap} takeOpenSe={takeOpenSe} />
        <ToolFrame list={list} selectedTool={(tool)} open={open}/>
      </Box>
    </OidcSecure>
  );
};

export default InternalArea;
```

ToolFrame.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import DrawerHeader from "../sidebar/DrawerHeader";
import Main from "../sidebar/Main";


const ToolFrame = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <Main open={props.open}>
      <DrawerHeader />
      {props.selectedTool}
    </Main>
  );
};

export default ToolFrame;
```